# Allow $_POST variables with rewrite rule .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, smarty

I'm triyin to do a page using MVC with PHP and Smarty, and [semantic URLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) (URL-rewriting).

So i have a main controllers that reads the name of controller and its action.

Example: /mypage/object/edit

the main controller after the rewrite reads: ?subtopic=object&action=edit

where "edit" is a function of the class "object".

So, i have a form in a .tpl (Smarty template) like this:

```
<form name="formulario" action="/mypage/imagen_del_dia/guardar" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td><div>Autor</div></td>
<td><input type='text' id='autor' value="{$username}" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div><input type='hidden' id='id' value="{$imagen.id}"/></td>
<td><input class="button_personalizado" type='submit' value='Editar' name='Editado'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When you clicked in submit, the .htaccess do this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^([0-9a-z_-]+)$ /mypage/index.php?subtopic=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([0-9a-z_-]+)/guardar$ /mypage/index.php?subtopic=$1&action=save [NC,L]
```

The idea is that the $_POST data can be read by:

```
/mypage/index.php?subtopic=$1&action=save
```

In this case the main controller open the class "imagen_del_dia" and its function "save"

The problem is that the $_POST data is lost in that point.

Comment: Your rules cannot break POST data

Comment: Are you saying that my rules are breaking the POST data or are you talking about that they don't break it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zerkms Thank you so much, you are right!

It's right the problem was the form, because i was using that form for a AJAX function, so the input had "id" tags, and in HTML must be "name" tags.

So i rename all "id" for "name", and now works fine!

Example:

```
<td><div><input type='hidden' name='id' value="{$imagen.id}"/></td>
```

Another tip is that i wasn't putting the **print_r($_POST);** in the right place, because my page is a class, you need put in the end of the class before of the **?>** tag in your PHP page.

Thanks!